# Returning value from jquery array

Tags: jquery, arrays

I created a simple html that enumerates names, with people's names on it as classes.  I then get the class name and check it against the array.  the result is undefined.  here's my code:

```
var prof_name = $(this).attr('class');
var n = prof_name.split(' ');
var name_out = n[0];

var nameList = {'rom':'Rommel Santiago','holy':'Holiander Fields'};
var nameValue = nameList.nameout;

alert(nameValue); //this pops up as undefined

alert(nameList.rom) // this pops up as 'Rommel Santiago'
```

What did i missed?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is you're referencing your array incorrectly.  I'm assuming your class name for `$(this)` is `rom holy`

You're retrieving `rom` like this: `var name_out = n[0];`

And you want to reference the `rom` key in `nameList`, which you can like this:

```
var nameValue = nameList[name_out];
```

After doing this, your updated code will look like this:

```
var prof_name = $(this).attr('class');
var n = prof_name.split(' ');
var name_out = n[0];

var nameList = {'rom':'Rommel Santiago','holy':'Holiander Fields'};
var nameValue = nameList[name_out];

alert(nameValue); //this pops up as Rommel Santiago
```

Working Example: http://jsfiddle.net/6GM7T/2/

---

**Furthermore**

I'd advise you to not use classes for storing data.

You can use the `data` attribute tag instead, like this:

```
<div id="myDiv" data-name="Rommel Santiago"></div>
```

And you can easily retrieve that data with jQuery using this:

```
$('#myDiv').data('name'); //returns Rommel Santiago
```

Comment: hi Axel, i still get the same result.  if i alert nameList.name_out, i get undefined.  If I alert nameList.rom then I get the value.  It would appear that the name_out value is incorrectly formatted.

Comment: Can you post the HTML you're attempting to retrieve these values from?

Comment: I've updated my answer with the solution.  I believe you're just referencing your array incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the OP wants to use the value of `name_out` as the index to `nameList`, in which case:

```
var nameValue = nameList.nameout;
```

should be:

```
var nameValue = nameList[name_out];
```

Answer (score 1):

As they said

It works with this

```
var prof_name = "rom holy";
var n = prof_name.split(' ');
var name_out = n[0];
alert("Parameter Selected = "+name_out);
var nameList = {'rom':'Rommel Santiago','holy':'Holiander Fields'};
var nameValue = nameList[name_out];

alert("From Object : "+nameValue); //this pops up as undefined

alert("Actual Value = "+nameList.rom) // this pops up as 'Rommel Santiago'
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Kartheek/nx3WQ/1/

if you call like nameList.nameout it actually searching for nameout as a  parameter in namelist

if u use nameList[nameout] it searches for index nameout value.